# Could not find method path() for arguments

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk

Please someone help me, I'm stuck here.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android{

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.glitchrun.sapphire"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "$projectDir/jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=$projectDir/jni/Application.mk"
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi", "arm64-v8a", "x86"
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
}
```

This is my error and I don't know what to do.

```
Could not find method path() for arguments [C:\Users\costy\AndroidStudioProjects\android\app/jni/Android.mk] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions.
```

I'm trying to export a .apk file and I was stuck with the Deprecated NDK problem. Now I'm stuck with this problem.

Comment: What gradle version are you using? In your `gradle.properties`.

Comment: @JakeSteam classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

Answer (score 2):

The `externalNativeBuild` block that specifies the makefile path should not be part of `defaultConfig`, but of its `android` parent:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    // etc...

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.glitchrun.sapphire"
        // etc...

        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=$projectDir/jni/Application.mk"
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi", "arm64-v8a", "x86"
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }

    // etc...

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "$projectDir/jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }
}
```

The inner one is used to modify [`ExternalNativeBuildNdkOptions`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions.html), while the outer one is used to modify [`NdkBuildOptions`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkBuildOptions.html).